# video list autoplay then loop again from begin

Tags: javascript, html, loops, video

I get code to create Html Video playlist,
code =>

```
<video id="myVideo" controls autoplay>
    <source src="upload/video/1.mp4" id="mp4Source" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="upload/video/2.mp4" id="mp4Source" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<script type='text/javascript'>
   var count=1;
   var player=document.getElementById('myVideo');
   var mp4Vid = document.getElementById('mp4Source');
   player.addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);

   function myHandler(e)
   {
  // How to Looping video play list -----

      if(!e) 
      {
         e = window.event; 
      }
      count++;
      $(mp4Vid).attr('src', "video/video"+count+".mp4");
      player.load();
      player.play();
   }

</script>
```

This code can load and autoplay video list very well ( play video 1, then play video 2, then return loop playing  video 2). But can't looping video from start again ( video 1 ).

Question => " How to create video list autoplay (video1, video2, ... ,last video) and then looping from start again"

Thank's for help...

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you can update/improve.

```
<video id="myVideo" controls autoplay>
    <source src="upload/video/1.mp4" id="mp4Source" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<script type='text/javascript'>
   var index=1;
   var count=%COUNT%; // replace it with whatever number last video has. 
   var player=document.getElementById('myVideo');
   var mp4Vid = document.getElementById('mp4Source');
   player.addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);

   function myHandler(e)
   {
      // How to Looping video play list -----
      index++;
      if (index > count) index = 1;
      $(mp4Vid).attr('src', "video/video"+index+".mp4");
      player.load();
      player.play();
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank's for fast respon, I'll try first

Comment: this output code have same result, ( play video 1, then play video 2, then return loop playing video 2). But can't looping video from start again ( video 1, video 2, last video, then looping for video 1, video 2, last video ).
Thank's

Comment: @dewokaji
What did you set to %COUNT%?

Comment: yes I did, I set -> var count=2;  -> for 2 sample video. 
is that right?

Comment: that's strange. what's the behavior? after video2 is finished, what do you see?

Comment: ,for 2 sample video, this output  code -> video 1, video 2, reload/ looping video2